# Issues with saving 'terra' asc files - "Couldn't find data values in ASCII Grid file"?

Tags: r, terra

Reproducible example from my dataset;

```
library(terra)
ext1_boreal <- ext(-154.529, -104.855, 47.663, 70.4789)
x <- rast(ext1_boreal, res=.1, crs="epsg:4326")
values(x) <- 1:ncell(x)

ext_EcoZone1 <- ext(-140.999, -122.812, 56.408, 64.700)
EcoZone2 <- vect(ext_EcoZone1, crs="epsg:4326")
x <- mask(x, EcoZone2)
f <- "D:/GitHub/MyProject/Outputs/Rasters/Explanatory/Testx.asc"
writeRaster(x, filename=f, overwrite=TRUE)
```

The problem:

```
Warning: D:/GitHub/MyProject/Outputs/Rasters/Explanatory/Testx.asc: Couldn't find data values in ASCII Grid file. (GDAL error 1)Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: D:/GitHub/MyProject/Outputs/Rasters/Explanatory/Testx.asc
```

Why is this warning coming up? Using: Package terra version 1.7-71, R version 4.3.3.

I have been unable to export an acs (ESRI ASCII) Spatraster for my data. I can export tif without issues. I need the acs format to run [another piece of software](https://climatena.ca/) that runs off acs format. I am able to take Spatraster tif files into QGIS and individual save them as acs files that can then be imported back into R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same error with the CRAN version of "terra" (1.7-71). The reason is that the NODATA value written to file is "nan"

```
f <- paste0(tempfile(), ".asc")
writeRaster(x, filename=f, overwrite=TRUE)
#Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: c:\temp\RtmpmYSDeo\file24704e227b7.asc
#In addition: Warning message:
#file24704e227b7.asc: Couldn't find data values in ASCII Grid file. (GDAL error 1) 

readLines(f, 7)
#[1] "ncols        497"              
#[2] "nrows        228"              
#[3] "xllcorner    -154.529000000000"
#[4] "yllcorner    47.663000000000"  
#[5] "cellsize     0.100000000000"   
#[6] "NODATA_value nan"                                                 
#[7] "nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
```

I do not see that problem in the development version of "terra"

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.7.74
> readLines(f, 6)
[1] "ncols        497"              
[2] "nrows        228"              
[3] "xllcorner    -154.529000000000"
[4] "yllcorner    47.663000000000"  
[5] "cellsize     0.100000000000"   
[6] "NODATA_value  4294967295"  
[7] " 4294967295.0 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295  ...
```

You can install the development version with

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

Note that this also works without the separate call to `writeRaster`

```
x <- mask(x, EcoZone2, filename=f, overwrite=TRUE)
```

I see that this works for integer rasters, but not for rasters with real (floating point) values. The odd thing is that it does work with the example (if you use `x/2`). This may be because it is not a very large dataset and GDAL detects the real numbers in the first part of the file, whereas it does not do that correctly with your data).

This should be fixed but here is a work-around. You can set the `NAflag` manually so a value outside of the range of your actual values. For example

```
writeRaster(x, filename=f, overwrite=TRUE, NAflag=-9999)

readLines(f, 6)
#[1] "ncols        497"              
#[2] "nrows        228"              
#[3] "xllcorner    -154.529000000000"
#[4] "yllcorner    47.663000000000"  
#[5] "cellsize     0.100000000000"   
#[6] "NODATA_value  -9999" 
#" -9999.0 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999
```

Comment: Space remaining on hard drive is small. I tested if this is a disk memory problem by installing everything onto a new 2TB external, including setting my tempfile storage to the new external. I still get the error: "Couldn't find data values in ASCII Grid file. (GDAL error 1)". The file shows up in the location with 474 KB and it has a 1 KB .prj file as well.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was a version difference. I was using the development version and with that version this works.

Comment: Okay...the developer version worked for me also. Thank you!

Comment: I spoke too soon. When I use my actual data I get the same error.  I do not understand how to address this: > readLines(f, 6) [1] "ncols        13734"             "nrows        6308"              "xllcorner    -154.529718084393" [4] "yllcorner    47.663427060903"   "cellsize     0.003616909119"    "NODATA_value nan"

Comment: That is probably because your values have real (not integer) numbers. I have expanded my answer to show how you can avoid this problem by setting the `NAflag`

Comment: Full follow up answer posted here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/479272/running-climate-models-with-climatena-and-asc-ascii-spatraster-causes-run?noredirect=1#comment781885_479272